# how to train custom word2vec embeddings to find related articles?

Tags: word-embeddings, nlp, embeddings

I am beginner in machine learning. My project is to make search engine based on AI which shows related articles when  we search on website. For this i decided to train my own embedding.

I found two methods for this:

- One is to train network to find next word( i.e inputs=[the quick,the quick brown,the quick brown fox] and outputs=[brown, fox,lazy]
- Other method is to train with nearest words(i.e [brown,fox],[brown,quick],[brown,quick]).

Which method should i use and after training how should i convert the sentence to a single vector to apply cosine similarity means sentence- the quick brown fox will return 4 vectors how should i convert it to feed for cosine similarity(which takes only one vector) with another sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I find your question bit convoluted, so I will answer with the following bullet points:

- **Train your own word embeddings**: There are many implementations out there, [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) is one.
- **Find related articles**: On that point, without being an expert, I would suggest to do some research on [Topic Modelling](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/11/understanding-nlp-topic-modeling-part-1.html). There are also a lot of libraries you can use.
- **Word embeddings to sentence embeddings**: This process is not as straightforward, the semantics change just by adding words together. You can use [Word Mover's Distance](https://markroxor.github.io/gensim/static/notebooks/WMD_tutorial.html) or numerous other which train in a supervised way [sentence embeddings](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers) or [unsupervised](https://github.com/epfml/sent2vec).